# Android CSS issue: fantom white overlay (zoomable and touchable) in every browser very strange

Tags: android, html, css, web

I made a website and check it in every browser. All browsers is ok but Android is not.

After ~30% of website height there is white overlay up to end of page.

This bug displays in every Android browser, like Chrome or stock browser app. I check that with BrowserStack.

First of all, website is [here](http://blackbat.citprofi.nebesniy.com).

Screenshots that display bug:

[screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vU2fK.png)

[screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4JdrI.png)

I made video to show this bug: https://youtu.be/UbXp7o-v64Y

Actually, what I'm trying but that is not worked:

- Remove overflow-x
- Set z-index 9999 for html and body
- Turn off all scripts
- Comment some sections in HTML

I know that bug is in [style.css](http://blackbat.citprofi.nebesniy.com/style.css) because if I remove `<link>` bug is disappear (with all styles of course)

How I can check what is this? I have not any debug tool on android. Any ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that! Oh my god, how it's stupid.

Actually I have `html, body { -webkit-filter: saturate(1.15); filter: saturate(1.15); }` and when I remove it, everything is OK!

It's a magic and I don't know how it is works.